# Django runserver getting stuck on strptime

Tags: python, django, pandas

In my django project, `python manage.py runserver` runs extremely slowly. To check where the problem is I run `python -v manage.py check`. This shows that it's getting stuck on:

```
# C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\dataenv\lib\__pycache__\_strptime.cpython-39.pyc matches C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\dataenv\lib\_strptime.py
# code object from 'C:\\Users\\mvren\\miniconda3\\envs\\dataenv\\lib\\__pycache__\\_strptime.cpython-39.pyc'
import '_strptime' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000002084418A670>
```

When I delete `_strptime.py` from my `env`, it runs smoothly. But then my app doesn't work. Specifically, I get the following traceback:

```
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\dataenv\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\dataenv\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\dataenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\dataenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\dataenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\dataenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\dataenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\dataenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\dataenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 412, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\dataenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\dataenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\dataenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\dataenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\dataenv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\mvren\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\datanz\datasite_old\datasite\urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\mvren\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\datanz\datasite_old\datasite\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from data.dash_lab import ur_latest
  File "C:\Users\mvren\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\datanz\datasite_old\data\dash_lab.py", line 28, in <module>
    df_lab['qpc'] = df_lab.groupby('Series_reference').Data_value.pct_change()
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\dataenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3634, in __setitem__
    indexer = convert_to_index_sliceable(self, key)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\dataenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2336, in convert_to_index_sliceable
    res = idx._get_string_slice(str(key))
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\dataenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimelike.py", line 236, in _get_string_slice
    parsed, reso = self._parse_with_reso(key)
  File "C:\Users\mvren\miniconda3\envs\dataenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimelike.py", line 231, in _parse_with_reso
    parsed, reso_str = parsing.parse_time_string(label, self.freq)
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\parsing.pyx", line 321, in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_time_string
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\parsing.pyx", line 355, in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_datetime_string_with_reso
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\parsing.pyx", line 509, in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing._parse_dateabbr_string
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_strptime'
```

I don't really understand, because I'm not using `'strptime` anywhere? How can I solve this?

Answer (score -1):

are you using a virtual environment?
if yes try to delete the virtual env , and create a new environment and install all the packages.

Or change the python version python3.10 or python3.8 and create virtual environment on python3.8 or python3.10

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).